# How to extend trial or enter product key in Visual Studio Express 2013 on an offline machine

Tags: license, visual-studio-2013

I can't sign in to Visual Studio on this machine because it is not connected to the Internet.
My 30-day trial period has expired, and I'm no longer able to use this product.

Is there any workaround that I can use to activate or register the product?

(I intentionally installed Express version of Studio because as far as I knew it's free, and it wouldn't need registration or other validation methods, because this is an offline machine.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about alternate software activation techniques after trial has expired.

Comment: I don't think it is an off-topic question, because this is a problem what I don't know how to solve, while others may know. Additionally there might be other users who also face this problem. Do you have a solution?